Unhandled Runtime Error - TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
enter image description here

"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { Check, ChevronsUpDown } from "lucide-react";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
    Command,
    CommandEmpty,
    CommandGroup,
    CommandInput,
    CommandItem,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import {
    Popover,
    PopoverContent,
    PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";

interface Framework {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

const frameworks: Framework[] = [
    {
        value: "next.js",
        label: "Next.js",
    },
    {
        value: "sveltekit",
        label: "SvelteKit",
    },
    {
        value: "nuxt.js",
        label: "Nuxt.js",
    },
    {
        value: "remix",
        label: "Remix",
    },
    {
        value: "astro",
        label: "Astro",
    },
];

export function SearchBox() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>("");

    const handleSelect = (currentValue: string) => {
        setValue((prevValue) =>
            currentValue === prevValue ? "" : currentValue
        );
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const selectedFramework = frameworks.find(
        (framework) => framework.value === value
    );

    const selectedLabel = selectedFramework
        ? selectedFramework.label
        : "Select framework...";

    console.log("Frameworks array:", frameworks); // Add this line to debug

    return (
        <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <Button
                    variant="outline"
                    role="combobox"
                    aria-expanded={open}
                    className="w-[200px] justify-between">
                    {selectedLabel}
                    <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                </Button>
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0">
                <Command>
                    <CommandInput placeholder="Search framework..." />
                    <CommandEmpty>No framework found.</CommandEmpty>
                    <CommandGroup>
                        {Array.isArray(frameworks) && frameworks.length > 0 ? ( // Defensive check
                            frameworks.map((framework) => (
                                <CommandItem
                                    key={framework.value}
                                    onSelect={() =>
                                        handleSelect(framework.value)
                                    }>
                                    <Check
                                        className={cn(
                                            "mr-2 h-4 w-4",
                                            value === framework.value
                                                ? "opacity-100"
                                                : "opacity-0"
                                        )}
                                    />
                                    {framework.label}
                                </CommandItem>
                            ))
                        ) : (
                            <CommandEmpty>No framework found.</CommandEmpty>
                        )}
                    </CommandGroup>
                </Command>
            </PopoverContent>
        </Popover>
    );
}


The error message TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) suggests that somewhere in my code, an attempt is being made to iterate over an undefined value. This is most likely happening in the frameworks.map function.
I try carefully walk through the code and see where the problem might be.
Ensure that frameworks is properly defined and imported:
The frameworks array is defined within the same file and should not be causing this issue directly.
I already check if the issue is caused by another part of my application:
Ensure that all the dependencies are correctly imported.
Confirm that the components used (Popover, Command, etc.) are correctly implemented and do not have issues on their own.
